# No hands detection in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion, oculus

I have downloaded core assets of Leap Motion from the official [website](https://developer.leapmotion.com/downloads/unity). What I was trying to do is to see my hands in Oculus Rift. There are some predefined scenes that are already added into core assets, for example [500Blocks](https://developer.leapmotion.com/libraries/374). However, when I'm trying to load this scene I just get a scene with blocks but hands are not detected. I'm pretty sure that Oculus Rift and Leap Motion are turned on. You can see on the picture of what I get.

[image]

What I want is simply to have detected my hands and being able to interact with cubes. How can I do this?

I have Leap Motion of 2.2.7, Oculus Rift 2, and Unity 5.1.1. I built the scene and launched the version with directToRift.

Comment: The error you have could mean that you have another application that uses Leap Motion that is opened.

Comment: Hmmm.. .Okay I reboot my computer and I got hands in Visualiser, but in the standard demo like 500Cubes, I'm not able to interact with cubes. Leap motion is just used as a camera. How can I make it interact?

Answer (score 0):

Is your leap motion plugged into oculus rift (won't work) or directly to your machine? (more likely to work)

Is your leap motion working fine, e.g. try the Visualizer while oculus rift is running

Comment: No. Just tried no response. What can the reason? Leap are connected to computer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "Allow Images" enabled in the Leap Motion Control Panel (accessible through the taskbar icon)? The white background suggests that passthrough is turned off. 500 Blocks uses our Image Hands assets, so passthrough is needed to see your hands.